# Characterization of certain analytic vector fields on $S^{2}$

Tags: complex-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems, foliations, real-analytic-structures

Let $X$ be  a real  analytic  vector  field on $S^{2}$ which satisfies:

1. $X$ has  a  finite number of  singularities on $S^{2}$
2. The equator is invariant under flow of $X$

3.$g_{*}X=\pm X$ where $g$ is the antipodal  map  $g(x,y,z)=(-x,-y,-z)$

> Can we say that $X$ is  topological equivalent to  the Poincare compactification of  a  polynomial vector  field  on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$?

This  is  motivated  by the  holomorphic  situation:Every one  dimensional singular holomorphic  foliation  of $\mathbb{C}P^{2}$ arise  from a polynomial vector  field(or polynomial one  form) on $\mathbb{C}^{2}$. See "Dynamics of singular holomorphic foliations by curves" by Saeid Zakeri, Contem. Math        $\;\;\;$ The  first version at http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9809099.pdf

Comment: I don't quite see why you speak about topological conjugacy in that case. Wouldn't you want something stronger, like orbital equivalence as foliated analytic spaces ? The topological setting destroys far too structure in my opinion, you take the risk of losing rigidity arising from analyticity.In the complex case, there is no such requirement, since all the usual charts on $\mathbb P_2(\mathbb C)$ are birationnally equivalent. This should also be the case in the real setting because stereographic projection is algebraic.

Comment: @LoïcTeyssier Could you please more explain why in this question, orbital equivalent is more appropriate than topological conjugacy? Moreover by orbital equivalent do you mean a homeomorphism send leaves to leaves regardless of parametrization? In this case, is not this weaker that topological conjugccy(rather than stronger)?

Comment: By «orbital equivalence» above I meant to speak of analytical orbital equivalence (=conjugacy), as opposed to topological orbital equivalence (=conjugacy) you speak of. I'm not sure topological equivalence is really what you want, but I can't speak in your stead.

Comment: @LoïcTeyssier so my question in the post is weaker than what you proposed.analytic conjugacy implies topological one. am I missing some things?

Comment: No, you're not missing anything. I just wanted to point out that since your motivation (foliations in $\mathbb P_2(\mathbb C)$) was not dealing with topological conjugacy, maybe you wanted a less general question. That's all…